# argument of type 'numpy.float64' is not iterable: python

Tags: python, numpy

```
import pylab as pl

a = 0.499901

ran = pl.frange(0.200001 , 0.5 , 0.00001)

for i in range(len(ran)):
    if a in ran[i]:
       print "all is good"
```

Error:

```
if a in ran[i]:

TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.float64' is not iterable
```

Can someone help me as this is just a testcase to a bigger problem and i would really like if someone could help me with this

Comment: ```a in ran[i]``` is linear search in some sequence. But you got no sequence (ran is, but not ```ran[i]```). You got a scalar. So either loop + equality check or get rid of loop and only use linear-search. And read also some basics about floating-point-math.

Comment: if i run this for loop with `print ran[i]`  then it gives me all the floating numbers

Comment: Yes (although it's ambiguous what you mean: all numbers are printed, one in each loop-iteration or all in each loop step; i expect the former) and? You know what ```in``` is doing?

Comment: `in` is checking if value of a is in that range?

Comment: Yes, linear-search in some iterable. Why not read the official docs?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop through all elements like this:

You can just use operator `in`

```
import pylab as pl
from __future__ import print_function

a = 0.499901
ran = pl.frange(0.200001 , 0.5 , 0.00001)
if a in ran:
    print('All is good')
```

Note that this statement won't print because `a in ran` is `false`.

If you still want to loop through all numbers (not efficient) you should redefine your `if` statement:

```
for i in range(len(ran)):
    if a == ran[i]:
        print "all is good"
```

Comment: 0.49901 is in the array `ran` so it's not technically False.

Comment: @MrinalMathur Please please please read the document i told you to. Without this basic knowledge, you won't come far. Sorry. In fp-math 0.1 == 0.05*2 is not necessarily true (random example).

Comment: Yep, reason it outputs `false` is described in the linked paper.